# Al pushear un resultado en un array, el array devuelve las sumas de los números, no el resultado final

Tags: javascript

Estoy probando el uso de funciones en js. A la hora de querer pushear un resultado, me da algo completamente distinto... En lugar de darme un array con [10] me da uno con [1,3,6,10].
Así que ahora tengo más dudas: ¿cómo meto el resultado total y... de dónde sale el segundo resultado?

```
const duplicado = [];
const numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function porCadaElemento(array, funcion) {
    for (const el of array) {
       funcion(el);
    }
}
let total = 0;

porCadaElemento(numeros, (el) => {
total += el;
duplicado.push(total);
});

console.log(numeros);
console.log(total);
console.log(duplicado);
```

Answer (score 0):

El push esta dentro de la función `porCadaElemento()`  por lo tanto cada vez que vas acumulando un número(es decir se hace un llamado a la función)va añadir ese valor dentro del array, si quieres que almacene la acumulación total pon `duplicado.push(total);` fuera de la función.